# Can we say "Some things end good, some things end bad" in informal American/Britain English?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, poetry, lyrics

I have a question about this sentence:

```
Some things end good, some things end bad
```

Could it be safely written in poetry or in the lyrics of a song?
I know that there are the adverbs `well` and `badly`, but I also read that `good` and `bad` can be used as adverbs too in some cases, examples (taken from Google Translate):

```
My mother could never cook this good

He beat her up real bad
```

That said, could the above phrase still be considered correct in the context of a song?

Thank you very much for your attention!

Comment: Lyrics are poetry. Most rules are off because creativity takes the day.

Comment: [These Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=end+well%2Cend+badly%2Cend+good%2Cend+bad%2Cend+up+good%2Cend+up+bad&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cend%20well%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cend%20badly%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cend%20good%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cend%20bad%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cend%20up%20good%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cend%20up%20bad%3B%2Cc0) at least hint at relative idiomaticities. The use of 'end' as a link verb is arguably non-standard.

Comment: Use 'turn out' or 'end up' if you can. As @YosefBaskin says, poetic license is the most significant thing...

Comment: Thank you guys! So, when someday you will hear a song with this line in the lyrics and someone will tell you "Oh, that line is not correct! Heresy!", please, tell them "Shut up! It's poetry. You didn't understand anything!" :) I will too :D

Well, I guess the same goes for the line `You and me could write a bad romance` of the Lady Gaga's song "Bad Romance". Whereas it should be `You and I could write a bad romance`, because `You and I` refers to the subject, Gaga seemed to choose `me` instead for stylistic purpose (the sentence doesn't really sound good with `You and I`).

Comment: You can say anything you like in informal English. That's why it's called "informal".